# How to autoscroll JScrollPane with JTextArea inside to the left

Tags: java, jscrollpane, jtextarea, autoscroll

I have `private JTextArea opisDiagnoza;` I insert it into `JScrollPane jsp`, like this:

```
opisDiagnoza = new JTextArea("Opis diagnozy:\n");
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(opisDiagnoza, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Later on, when I do:

`opisDiagnoza.setText(REALLY_LONG_TEXT);`

the `JScrollPane` autorscrolls to right, so to read the content I need to manually(by clicking horizontal scrollbar) scroll it to the left.

How to autoscroll `JScrollPane` to the left after inserting a text into `JTextArea` inside of it?

Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxc4x.png

I can't add image explicitly because of low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textArea.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

Comment: Could you add some text to explain what this is doing and why it solves the problem?